# About how people come up with Gamma distribution

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, math-history

The gamma distribution is given by $f(x)= \frac{1}{\Gamma(\alpha) \theta^{\alpha}} x^{\alpha-1} e^{\frac{-x}{\theta}}$. I know this is a special type of Poisson distribution where it is counting the n th an event is happening rather than one. I know $\Gamma(\alpha)$ is $(\alpha-1)!$ Question is, how people derive that formula? Is there an intuitive way to remember that?

Comment: It is actually a generalisation of an exponential distribution, where it is counting the $\alpha$th event of a [Poisson process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_point_process) rather than the first.  $\theta$ is a scaling factor

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it is not at all a Poisson distribution.  Poisson is a discrete distribution, this is continuous.  In a Poisson process, the Poisson distribution counts the number of events that happen in a given period of time, the Gamma distribution tells you how long a time it takes for a given number of events to occur.

The connection between them is: if $X$ has
a Poisson distribution with parameter $\lambda= t/\theta$ and $T$ has a Gamma distribution with parameters $\alpha$ and $\theta$ (where $\alpha$ is a positive integer),
$\mathbb P(T \le t) = \mathbb P(X \ge \alpha)$.  That is, the $\alpha$'th event happens by time $t$ if and only if there are at least $\alpha$ events up to time $t$.

Comment: No, you **don't** "know that $\Gamma(\alpha)= (\alpha- 1)!$" because $(\alpha- 1)!$ is only defined for $\alpha$ a non-negative integer while the gamma function is defined for $\alpha$ any positive number.  What is true is that $\Gamma(\alpha)= \alpha(\Gamma(\alpha- 1)$ =hich, for $\alpha$ a positive **integer** gives $\Gamma(\alpha)= (\alpha- 1)!$.